# WebAPI Controller Names with Underscores

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

WebAPI has a naming convention "FooController" for controller names. This is similar to ASP.NET MVC. Our codebase uses underscores to separate words in identifier named, e.g. "Foo_Bar_Object". In order for the controller names to follow this convention, we need a way to name our controllers "Foo_Controller".

Basically, we don't want URL routes to look like "oursite.com/api/foo_/", and we don't want to have to make exceptions everywhere for the underscore (e.g. route config, names of view folders, etc). To do this in MVC, we do:

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start() {

    ...

    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new Custom_Controller_Factory());
}
```

**Custom_Controller_Factory.cs**

```
public class Custom_Controller_Factory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override Type GetControllerType(RequestContext request_context, string controller_name)
    {
        return base.GetControllerType(request_context, controller_name + "_");
    }
}
```

This seems to completely take care of the problem all in once place in MVC. Is there a way to do the same for WebAPI? I've heard rumor of a DefaultHttpControllerFactory but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Uh what is the point of making all of this extra work for yourselves? `My_Class_Name` is non standard and I think anyone will suggest that you go with `MyClassName`.

Comment: That's purely subjective. Also, I don't decide the naming standard that my shop uses. We have decades of codebase precedent to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *DefaultHttpControllerSelector* is what you are looking for.

```
class CustomHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector {

   public CustomHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration) 
      : base(configuration) { }

   public override string GetControllerName(HttpRequestMessage request) {

      IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();
      string controller = (string)routeData.Values["controller"]

      return controller + "_";
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new sh_Custom_Http_Controller_Selector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

Comment: This was almost exactly what I needed. I updated the answer with a few tweaks. `GetControllerName` needed to be override, not virtual.  And I added a line for how to register it in the Global.asax. Thanks!